# Prove function is a semi-norm on linear-topological space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a linear-topological space; let $A$ be a convex, absorbing, balanced subset of X. Prove $\rho_{A}(x)$ is a semi-norm.

$$
\rho_{A}(x) = \left\{ \inf t > 0 : t^{-1}x \in A \right\}
$$

I am not so sure, $t > 0$ is sufficient. I feel something is misleading at $t \in (0,1)$.

$A$ set properties.

- **$A$ is balanced**.
  We have: for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such as $|\alpha| \leq 1$, we have $\alpha A \subseteq A$.
- **$A$ is absorbing.** We have: for all $x \in X$ exists $r > 0$, for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such as $|\alpha| \geq r$, $x \in \alpha A$.

Semi-norm axioms.

- **Subadditivity** -- $\rho(a + b) \leq \rho(a) + \rho(b)$.
- **Homogenity.** -- $\rho(\alpha a) = |\alpha| \rho(a)$.

So, we have

$$
\rho_{A} (a + b) = \left\{ \inf t > 0 : t^{-1}(a+b) \in A \right\}
$$

$$
\rho_{A} (a + b) = \left\{ \inf t > 0 : t^{-1}a + t^{-1}b) \in A \right\}
$$

How to use $A$ properties for next step of proof?

Comment: What do you mean about $t>0$ being sufficient?

Comment: It's just personal feeling. :) 
If we consider a __balanced__ property of a set $A$, it has a condition $|a| \leq 1$. If we take $t = \frac{1}{2}$, we have $t^{-1} = 2$ and we can no longer apply this property.

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you explain why?

Comment: The balanced property places no limitations whatsoever on the definition of the pseudo norm.

Comment: Rudin’s book on functional analysis has all the details in chapter one. IIRC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you! I have found a clear and natural explaination in Rudin's book.  It looks like seminorms on X turn out to be precisely, Mińkowski functionals of a balanced, convex and absorbing set.
Clear proof is on the page below the definition of $\rho$.